# ASP.NET ABP: Return an ISO DateTime(Not Local) from the DB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I am developing an application which needs to work in multiple locales/timezones. I have run into what should be a simple issue but because of the way ABP works, it is proving not so simple to fix.

Issue: ABP is retrieving DateTimes from the DB already pre-localised. I want to retrieve the DateTimes as ISO YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS so that when moment.js receives the data on the client-side I have a common starting point i.e. ISO. From there I can format easily to the correct locale.

I do not want to have to manually specify the format for each locale with a switch statement but rather create the moment from ISO like follows:

```
var date = moment('2020-05-22 10:05').utc(); //works for an ISO date

var date = moment('22/05/2020 10:05').utc(); //Invalid date

var date = moment('22/05/2020 10:05', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').utc(); //Works but I don't want to have to manually specify this for each locale.
```

But at present I cannot do this because the returned DateTime is always localised. The ABP & DotNetZero forums state that the DateTime should be returned as UTC but this does not seem to be the case.

- https://support.aspnetzero.com/QA/Questions/2737
- https://support.aspnetzero.com/QA/Questions/3799

Application_start() in global.asax also contains the following definition:

```
Clock.Provider = ClockProviders.Utc;
```

My controller code (sample naming)

```
var query = _someRepository.GetAll();

var rows = query.Select(a => new RowViewModel
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Name = a.Name,
    CreatedBy = a.CreatorUser.Name + " " + a.CreatorUser.Surname,
    CreatedOn = a.CreationTime //Returns 22/05/2020 10:05:05, I want 2020-05-22 10:05:05
});
```

*How can I get ABP to return as ISO date from my Controller/EF query?*
Any info would be welcome.

In answer to a comment below, this is what the DateTimeKind data looks like for the returned dates:

[image]

Comment: Could you show an actual example of your code retrieving and handling a DateTime instead of date string parsing? What type is `moment`? Also please add links to the documentation you are refering to.

Comment: @Filburt question updated now thanks.moment() as in from moment.js, thanks.

Comment: This forum reply sounds iffy: *"ABP does not do any operation on the date values send from client to server and vice versa, but .NET Framework does"*. .NET does exactly what you instruct it to do and doesn't do magical unknown operations on your data. Did you inspect `a.CreationTime` for its [DateTime.Kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=netcore-3.1). To me, it sounds like localization settings in ABP are somewhat messy.

Comment: @Filburt thanks for the reply and help. Much appreciated. I added in the Datetime.Kind debug data in the question above.

Comment: I'm unclear about the question, are you asking about what EF Core is returning from the database, or about how API calls return in json?  I just downloaded a fresh ABP solution and OOTB for me when I watch back-end calls with Fiddler they return like `2020-05-28T02:15:26.345`.  If that isn't the case for you, maybe `options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;` in AddNewtonsoftJson in Startup.cs?